# PosgtreSQL Optimize Query with st_transform, st_makepoint, and st_contains

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have the following query:

```
UPDATE  DestinTable
SET  destin = geomVal 
FROM GeomTable
WHERE st_contains(st_transform(geom, 4326), st_setsrid(
      st_makepoint(d_lon::double precision, d_lat::double precision), 4326));
```

This query works, but it is very slow. I have to run an update on a very large table, and it is taking a 8+ hours to complete (I run this on 5 different columns). **I wanted to know if there was a way to optimize this query to make it run faster**. I am unaware of the behind the scenes work associated with an st_contains() method, so there may be some obvious solutions that I am missing.

Comment: what is the original SRID for `DestinTable.geom` and why are you transforming it?

Comment: Please use fully qualified column names in your query. (add table aliases) It is unclear from your question from which of the two tables the columns stem from.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create an index on ST_TRANSFORM

```
CREATE INDEX idx_geom_4326_geomtable
  ON GeomTable
  USING gist
  (ST_Transform(geom, 26986))
  WHERE geom IS NOT NULL;
```

If you have all the fields in one SRID in the table it will be even easier to create a normal `GIST` index on that table and transform the point you're supplying to the local SRID